# Can't access nfs3 shares

Tags: server, nfs, share

Unable to access NFS shares on Ubuntu from Windows 7. It just acts like the share can't be found on network. (NET HELP MSG 1222)

**on client:**

```
added NFS features  
tried "mount IP:/share z:" and the gui drive mapping  
tried with and without "AnonymousUid""AnonymousGid" DWORDs under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ClientForNFS\CurrentVersion\Default
```

**on server:**

```
exportfs lists the shares.
mount shows "nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw)" (I think that's normal?!?)
have experimented with many options in:  
/etc/exports  
/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server  
/etc/default/nfs-common  
tried forcing no NFS v 4
after each change I'm restarting nfs service and re-exporting
```

I've been trying to figure this out forever. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: do you have a linux user (on the server) with the same name as the windows user and access to the filesystem?

Comment: Yes, I've also tried using other users from the client side as the client offers the ability to authenticate as somebody else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the issue was this default group policy needing to be disabled:
"Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (if server agrees)"
under gpedit.msc:
computer configuration>windows security>security settings>local policies>security options